# having problem in getting response of a complete ajax-php request in a div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm having problem in getting the response in a div of an ajax request which is made by onclick event by a form & a php page.

The code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript">
function commentRequest(counter) {
    new Ajax.Request("comment.php", 
    { 
        method: 'post', 
        postBody: 'commentbox='+ $F('commentbox_'+counter)+'&idc2='+$F('idc2_'+counter),
        onComplete: showResponse2
    });
}

function showResponse2(counter)
{
    document.getElementById('showcomments_'+counter).innerHTML= counter.responseText;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">
 <textarea name="text1" id="text1"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="nbbutton" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","myuser","Muddser@1");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 MySQL_select_db("mydb", $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY sl_no desc");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "$row['text1']";
}

$id=$row['sl_no'];



$queryout="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE idc='$idc'";
$resultout=mysql_query($queryout) or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultout))



echo "<div id='showcomments_$idc'>";
echo "<div id='comment'><form name='comment' id='commentfrm'onSubmit='return false;'>";
echo "<input type='text' value='Post a Comment' name='commentbox' id='commentbox_$idc' 

tabindex='30' size='56'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='idc2' value='$idc' id='idc2_$idc'>";
echo "&nbsp;<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' id='commentbtn' 

tabindex='40' onClick='commentRequest($idc)'>";
echo "</form></div>";

echo "$row1['comment']";

echo "</div>";


 </body>
 </html>
```

In the above thing, I submit some value of a textfield in a table & I get the output on the same page as the form is on.

in these outputs, I've made a provision of commenting on each outputs.

to comment I've created a form which calls an ajax function commentRequest($idc) as u can see it in the head tag.

after commeting by ajax, I wanna show the response of the form submission in tht very page in the div named showcomments_$idc.

Here, though I'm able to submit the value bt I'm totally unable to show the response in the desired div...

Plz help me if ne1 can...

I need it so badly as I've been stuck in between of my project...

Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Muddser

Comment: Does the target div exist in the DOM? Which JS error do you see?

Comment: When working with JS/Ajax, the Firebug extension for Firefox can offer you a lot of insight into what you're doing (requests and their response) and what is going wrong (errors). When an Ajax call is "not working", the cause can be an error in your JS, but just as well an error in your server side script. You need more information to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `showResponse2()` function you are treating `counter` as both string (when searching for element id) and object containing AJAX response (when assigning respose text). Change your function `commentRequest` to:

```
function commentRequest(counter) {
    new Ajax.Request("comment.php", 
    {
        method: 'post', 
        postBody: 'commentbox='+ $F('commentbox_'+counter)+'&idc2='+$F('idc2_'+counter),
        onComplete: function(response) {
            document.getElementById('showcomments_'+counter).innerHTML= response.responseText;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried it also friend... but it isn't working... the request completes but response is not at all shown... when I refresh the page then it shows one more comment added to it... plz help if u knw what else can be done?

Comment: Ok, I see it now after reformatting your code. The variable `counter` is unavailable in response handler, try the new `commentRequest()` from above. And open your browser's JavaScript console (eg. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) to look for errors, then fixing bugs like that will be easy.